# why font-awesome icon on react-redux not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, font-awesome

[image: instead of showing the icons i choose, it displayed a little blue box. but all the functionality is working]

```
class ShopCart extends Component {
  handleAddQuantity = id => {
    this.props.addQuantity(id);
  };

  handleSubtractQuantity = id => {
    this.props.subtractQuantity(id);
  };

  handleRemoveQuantity = id => {
    this.props.removeQuantity(id);
  };
  render() {
    let addedItems1 = this.props.items.map(item => {
      return (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>
            <NavLink to="/myCart">
              <span>
                <i
                  className="fas fa-plus-circle"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.handleAddQuantity(item.id);
                  }}
                ></i>
              </span>
            </NavLink>
            {item.quantity}
            <NavLink to="/myCart">
              <span>
                <i
                  className="fas fa-minus-circle"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.handleSubtractQuantity(item.id);
                  }}
                ></i>
              </span>
            </NavLink>
          </td>
          <td>${item.price1}</td>
          <td>
            <NavLink to="/myCart">
              <span>
                <i
                  className="fas fa-times"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.handleRemoveQuantity(item.id);
                  }}
                ></i>
              </span>
            </NavLink>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>
                <NavLink to="/" exact activeStyle={{ color: "green" }}>
                  <a href="#">back to store</a>
                </NavLink>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{addedItems1}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hi everyone, I am new to react, I am not sure how to insert font-awesome into react-redux, ideally I want to make an addition and minus icon to add and subtract quantity in the shopping cart, I have followed all the steps in the tutorial, first I used npm install --save font awesome and add import "../node_modules/font-awesome/CSS/font-awesome.min.css"; to index.js, then I tried to add font-awesome icons into component and turn out displayed a little blue box showed in the pic I uploaded but all the functionality works fine. can somebody give me a heads up?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I added link to the fontawesome cdn in my html that's works for me.

or you may froget to include css or font

Comment: thanks, but I don't really have a html, which file should i be adding the cdn?

Comment: In your project root dir you find index.html

Comment: thanks, i changed the icon from font-awesome 4 in stead of 5 and its working